# bxSlider customPager is causing li elements to have a width of 663px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I have an active bxSlider on a website I'm developing and want the theme's layout  preserved (see [here](http://www.type1wd.com/beta/moon/02_home-2.html/) under case study section).

Basically the bxSlider would rotate and the thumbnail pager images would remain stationary, but the active one would be highlighted.

However, setting the customPager as the thumbnail images causes it to seemingly turn into a carousel and each element is given a width of 663px.  I have tried numerous options (still trying) and have checked into similar issues but no solution has been found.

I don't mind posting the markup but there's a lot so I figured it might be better to supply the url where the problem is actually occurring.

Thanks for all and any help, I've been banging my head to figure it out for a few hours now.

Comment: Ah sorry about that....url has an extra '/' at the end...try [this one](http://www.type1wd.com/beta/moon/02_home-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so using jquery I was able to edit the width of the elements being created for the bxSlider...my other issue was that the thumbnail pager images were still moving, so here's how my js is currently in order to keep the thumbnail pager in place.  But the issue is that the main image is now displaying a duplicate pager:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.enable-bx-slider').bxSlider({
            pagerCustom: '#bx-pager-all',
            minSlides:1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            speed: 1000,
            auto: true,
            autoStart: true
        }).css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)');

  $('.enable-bx-slider').children().css('width', '115px');
    });
```

Comment: my apologies, I did not. I just refreshed the page and saw it.

However, that default functionality is already there...I'm trying to have it auto rotate the image being displayed like a carousel...except the pager doesn't move, instead stays stationary (like in your example)

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference on my end when removing all and adding one back in at a time...looking at it now it appears that the data- attributes eliminate the need for the custom js at the bottom of the doc?

Still can't figure out why the pager can't be kept still and the active tab just highlight blue with the corresponding main image rotating to match it

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reading the documentation and then checking the readme file, here's what I came up with...

The result is that the data- attributes on the html for the slider have stayed the same as the theme has them set by default.  All that needed to happen was the following js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slider = $('.bx-slider-all').bxSlider({
        pause: 10000
    });
});
slider.startAuto();
```

Now all that needs done is that I need to find out how to highlight the 'active' thumbnail when the main image changes...

Again the solution can be found [here](http://www.type1wd.com/beta/moon/02_home-2.html)

Comment: Sorry about the posting and what not...I know it's getting a little clustered.

And forgive me as I don't mean for this to come off as disrespectful to you by any means.  However, regarding the url I provided, did you view how the functionality of the bxSlider is operating?

What I mean is that the main display image is rotating and the thumbnails are staying where they are (which is great) but the problem is that the "active" class isn't changing from one thumbnail to another when the main image changes.

Comment: Yeah that css was already in the code and I was able to make the adjustments.  Thank you for that added css!

I'm not sure if this happens on your end now but when everything is running, now it's almost as if the highlighted thumbnails go past the 5 image loop (after the 5th item the thumbnails stop highlighting for the length of 2 main image slides before starting over). The weird thing is, there's only 5 items...

Comment: Yes I was using the .length property until I realized that the elements were being cloned.  However, I found the solution:

it was creating clones because it was set to 'infiniteLoop: true'...
Once set to false it now functions properly!